# Having Issues dividing the value from a numericUpdown from the value on a textbox and showing on a third textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I am very new to this site and to C# I am trying to build a Winforms app on VS 2017 that contains a numericUpDown, and 2 textboxes. I need to have the value from textbox 1 divided by the value on the numericUpDown control and then summarize and show the result inside the textbox 2 but in the form of a double. The problem I'm having is that nothing gets calculated until I change the value of the numericupdown up 3 times and then the summary result is wrong. It's off by 1 value change. So if I click up on the nud 3 times and the value on textbox 1 is 0.28 it should give me a result of 0.09333333 which is 0.28 divided by 3 but it's giving me 0.14 instead. If I click down on the nud it looks like it's dividing by zero. Can the fact that the numericupdown starts at 0 value have anything to do with my issue? I am not getting any error message or exceptions when I run the app. I'd appreciate any help. Please don't be too hard on me I am super new in c# Thanks

Here's the code

```
    private void numericUpDown1R2Scrap_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double val1 = 0.0;
        double val2 = 0.0;
        double total = 0.0;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1WeightSummary.Text) && 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(numericUpDown1R2Scrap.Text))
        {


            val1 = double.Parse(numericUpDown1R2Scrap.Text);
            val2 = double.Parse(textBox1WeightSummary.Text);

            if (val1 != 0)
            {
                total = val2 / val1;
                textBox1RingWeightTotal.Text = total.ToString(); 
            }
```

Comment: This is a common ordinary debugging issue.  There likely **is** something happening the first 2 times, it is just that the result is too small.  Learn how to debug your code as this is not the last buggy code you will write.  **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**.  It will also help you write better code because you will better understand how code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ValueChanged` is raised before the `Text` property is updated: so the contents of `numericUpDown1R2Scrap.Text` will be outdated when handling `ValueChanged`. Use the `Value` property instead, which will have the up-to-date value. It's already a numeric type so you don't need to parse it either (but you do need to cast it since it's `decimal` while you're using `double`):

```
val1 = (double)numericUpDown1R2Scrap.Value;
val2 = double.Parse(textBox1WeightSummary.Text);
```

Comment: Jeff E Your solution worked like a charm. Thank you so very much!! Who would of thought it was such a simple fix. It took me a few days of trying to figure it out on my own, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In the Form Designer, set the NumericUpDown `Minimum` and `Value` properties to 1.  This allows to start from 1 and it won't allow to go down to `0`.

Then, always inspect the `NumericUpDown.Value` to read the current value, which is a `decimal` type.

Use [Decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) to convert the numeric input of a TextBox. Note that the default implementation supposes you're using the current Culture decimal separator.  See the Docs about using the `InvariantCulture` reference to force the use of a dot as decimal separator and a comma as thousands separator, if needed.

```
private void numericUpDown1R2Scrap_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NumericUpDown nUpDown = sender as NumericUpDown;
    if (nUpDown.Value == 0) nUpDown.Value = 1;
    if (decimal.TryParse(textBox1WeightSummary.Text, out decimal inputValue)) {
        textBox1RingWeightTotal.Text = (inputValue / nUpDown.Value).ToString();
    }
}
```

This line: **`if (nUpDown.Value == 0) nUpDown.Value = 1;`** is a fail-safe, in case one forgot to set the NumericUpDown `Value` and `Minimum` to `1` in the designer (or in the Form's constructor).

This line: **`NumericUpDown nUpDown = sender as NumericUpDown;`**, is used retrieve the instance of the NumericUpdown control that raised the event. This allows to reuse the code for any other NumericUpDown control without manually changing the reference.

This syntax: **`decimal.TryParse([Some string], out decimal inputValue)`** requires `C# 7.0+`.
If you're using a previous version of the language, you need to declare the local variable outside the method:

```
decimal inputValue = 0m;
if (decimal.TryParse(textBox1WeightSummary.Text, out inputValue)) { ... }
```

In this line: **`(inputValue / nUpDown.Value).ToString();`**, you could change the ToString() format, specifying the number of decimals to use. For example:

```
(inputValue / nUpDown.Value).ToString("N2");
```

will output a decimal number formatted to show with just the first 2 decimal positions.